Issue with `tcolorbox` record option together with math delimiters `\( \)` in the title
According to the answer here, I record some tcolorbox.
All is working fine except to the titles containing maths with delimiters \( \)which I prefer compared with dollars. Do you know a workaround ?
MWE
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,french]{book}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{tcb@cnt@meth}[chapter]
\newcommand{\themethcounter}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{tcb@cnt@meth}}
\NewTColorBox{meth}{ O{} m m }
  {%
    theorem={Méthode}{tcb@cnt@meth}{#2}{meth:#3},
    enhanced, breakable,
    fonttitle=\bfseries, separator sign dash,
    sharp corners,
    first use/.style={
      saveto=\jobname_meth-\themethcounter.tex,
      record={%
        \string\begin{meth}[first use/.style={}, #1]{#2}{#3:replay}%
          \string\input{\jobname_meth-\themethcounter.tex}%
        \string\end{meth}%
      },
      lowerbox=ignored,
    },
    #1
  }

\begin{document}

\chapter{Premier}

\tcbstartrecording\relax

%OK
\begin{meth}[first use]{$x$}{first}
First method
\tcblower
Print only at the end of the chapter, not during the first print (1).
\end{meth}

%KO
%\begin{meth}[first use]{\(x\)}{second}
%Second method
%\tcblower
%Print only at the end of the chapter, not during the first print (2).
%\end{meth}

\section*{Liste of all the methods}

\tcbstoprecording
\setcounter{tcb@cnt@meth}{0}
\tcbinputrecords

\end{document}


It's not only a question of math delimiter. $\sum x^n$ or \emph{x} in the title also raise errors.

The code compiles if in the key record, #2 is replaced by \unexpanded{#2}. Then \(x\) can be used.
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,french]{book}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{tcb@cnt@meth}[chapter]
\newcommand{\themethcounter}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{tcb@cnt@meth}}
\NewTColorBox{meth}{ O{} m m }
  {%
    theorem={Méthode}{tcb@cnt@meth}{#2}{meth:#3},
    enhanced, breakable,
    fonttitle=\bfseries, separator sign dash,
    sharp corners,
    first use/.style={
      saveto=\jobname_meth-\themethcounter.tex,
      record={%
        \string\begin{meth}[first use/.style={}, #1]{\unexpanded{#2}}{#3:replay}%
          \string\input{\jobname_meth-\themethcounter.tex}%
        \string\end{meth}%
      },
      lowerbox=ignored,
    },
    #1
  }

\begin{document}

\chapter{Premier}

\tcbstartrecording\relax

%OK
\begin{meth}[first use]{$x$}{first}
First method
\tcblower
Print only at the end of the chapter, not during the first print (1).
\end{meth}

%KO
\begin{meth}[first use]{\(x\)}{second}
Second method
\tcblower
Print only at the end of the chapter, not during the first print (2).
\end{meth}

\section*{Liste of all the methods}

\tcbstoprecording
\setcounter{tcb@cnt@meth}{0}
\tcbinputrecords

\end{document}



This solve issues with other patterns, like $\sum x^n$ or \emph{x}. Nice.
